# Kubernetes kubectl update service selector

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

My Kubernetes cluster is running under Google Cloud. I have deployment which running with port 443 and LoadBalancer expose it to the internet.

I created it in this way:

```
kubectl expose deployment my-app --target-port=443 --port=443 --type=LoadBalancer
```

After running this command, the loadbalancer is pointing to `my-app` deployment. Now I created `my-app2` and I want to change the loadbalancer to point the new deployment (`my-app2`).

**Note:** Delete and re-create the deployment is releasing the external IP address and I want to avoid it.

How to patch the existing service to point another deployment *without* loosing the external IP?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally, found the solution:

```
kubectl patch service old-app -p '{"spec":{"selector":{"app": "new-app"}}}'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in the tutorial for GKE [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip).

Firstly, you should reserve a static IP address, so that it is re-used between deployments.

You can do this in the GCP console or via the command, like so:
`gcloud compute addresses create helloweb-ip --region us-central1`

Then you can find the static IP address you have been allocated:
`gcloud compute addresses describe helloweb-ip --region us-central1`

Then you should use this IP address when setting up your `LoadBalancer` service. In "imperative" commands, you would type:

`kubectl expose deployment my-app --target-port=443 --port=443 --type=LoadBalancer --loadBalancerIP=YOUR.IP.ADDRESS.HERE`

The YAML "declarative" form is convenient as the setup gets more complex, this can also saved for re-use in future. For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: helloweb
  labels:
    app: hello
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello
    tier: web
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: "YOUR.IP.ADDRESS.HERE"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use already existing service to point new deployment.

All you've to do, edit the service YAML with newly deployed service's label.

### Example

Suppose, you've newly deployed services yaml as below.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app-2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

It has label as

```
template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app-2
```

If your service is as below:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

you only need to change selector section of service

```
selector:
    app: my-app
```

to

```
selector:
    app: my-app-2
```

Comment: Nice. What if it's not newly deployment (existing one)?

Comment: then only you need to add existing deployment's labels to service's selector

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever does it help?

Comment: Yes, this is one type of solution. I prefer the other solution, mentioned here. Thanks for help!